# Regexkit lite and iPhone parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, parsing

I've taken the suggestion of some posts here that recommend regexkit lite with a problem I am having with trying to extract a particular URL from a string. The problem is that I'm very lost with the syntax of using it and hoping someone that has used it can give me a hand.

The string i'm trying to parse looks someting like this:

```
<a> blah blah blah <img src="http://www.something.com/1234.jpg">
```

All I want to extract is only the 1234. It would be after a "/" and before ".jpg"

How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to parse any string that looks like /1234.jpg, then regular expressions are a good way to go. If you need strings that look like that **only in `img` tags**, then use an HTML parser, not regex.

If it's the first case, this expression will match "`/1234.jpg`". You can get rid of the `/` and `.jpg` parts easily.

```
(/.+?\\.jpg)
```

The expression reads "look for any string starting with `/`, ending with `.jpg` and containing anything in between."

And using look-aheads and look-behinds, this one matches just "`1234`":

```
(?<=/).+?(?=\\.jpg)
```

This expression reads "look behind for `/`, match anything until `.jpg` is next."

Comment: I tried 
NSString *regExString = @"(/.+?\\.jpg)";
NSString *matchedString = [dataString stringByMatching:regExString capture:1L];

I got everything BUT what I was looking for. Did I do something wrong?

and got everything BUT the

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recipe you should be able to adapt, from RegexKitLite's documentation:

```
NSString *searchString =@"http://johndoe:secret@www.example.com:8080/private/mail/index.html";
NSString *regexString  = @"\\b(https?)://(?:(\\S+?)(?::(\\S+?))?@)?([a-zA-Z0-9\\-.]+)(?::(\\d+))?((?:/[a-zA-Z0-9\\-._?,'+\\&%$=~*!():@\\\\]*)+)?";

if([searchString isMatchedByRegex:regexString]) {
  NSString *protocolString = [searchString stringByMatching:regexString capture:1L];
  NSString *userString     = [searchString stringByMatching:regexString capture:2L];
  NSString *passwordString = [searchString stringByMatching:regexString capture:3L];
  NSString *hostString     = [searchString stringByMatching:regexString capture:4L];
  NSString *portString     = [searchString stringByMatching:regexString capture:5L];
  NSString *pathString     = [searchString stringByMatching:regexString capture:6L];

  NSMutableDictionary *urlDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

  if(protocolString) { [urlDictionary setObject:protocolString forKey:@"protocol"]; }
  if(userString)     { [urlDictionary setObject:userString     forKey:@"user"];     }
  if(passwordString) { [urlDictionary setObject:passwordString forKey:@"password"]; }
  if(hostString)     { [urlDictionary setObject:hostString     forKey:@"host"];     }
  if(portString)     { [urlDictionary setObject:portString     forKey:@"port"];     }
  if(pathString)     { [urlDictionary setObject:pathString     forKey:@"path"];     }

  NSLog(@"urlDictionary: %@", urlDictionary);
}
```